# Color of Tyranosaurus Rex

Tags: palaeontology

What is the color of T Rex. popularly in movies like Jurrasic Park, they display the T rex as green, but is that true. Evidence suggests that T Rex was covered by feathers but recent Studies suggest that it is not the case rather like reptiles they were covered with scaly skin. The color, is basically the wavelength not absorbed by the melanin, and reflected off it like our skin, synthesized in special melanosomes. studies suggest ball shaped melanosomes are containing red melanin and sausage shaped contain black. By studying the shapes of these melanosomes scientists estimated the color of the scales being reddish brown, but is that true, if so, why do most herbivores and many carnivores being greenish and T Rex being brownish?

Thanks in advanced and please don't  mind if my question is silly